# Google Analytics iframe+query string tracking

Tags: google-analytics, query-string, multiple-domains

I wondered if anyone can point me in the right direction?

I have an iframe sitting on us.website.com, embedded inside a page on www.website.com - and I need to track each query string in google analytics for the us.website.com page.

i.e.

I have the query string data passing from the URL (address bar) to the iframe so when a form is submitted a tracking code identifies where the user came from.

www.website.com/offers/offer.html?src=source1 (form passes source1 as the entry source)
www.website.com/offers/offer.html?src=source2 (form passes source2 as the entry source)

Currently, all of the (us.website.com/offers/offer.asp) stats are shown under this one .asp page - but I need it to show stats for each query string.

i.e.

us.website.com/offers/offer.asp?src=source1 - individual stats
us.website.com/offers/offer.asp?src=source2 - individual stats

Is there a way to do this without building two separate .asp pages on the us.website.com domain??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to [create view](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034823?hl=en) in GA panel (filtered data). Of course you can tell GA to track different URL on every page, depending on parsed `source` but you are reinventing wheel, use [filters](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034823?hl=en).

```js
var url = '/someofakename.asp?ada'
try {
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-Y']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', url]);
} catch(err) {
 //handle errors
}
```

Comment: I should point out I only have Google Analytics access for the us.website.com domain and not for www.website.com.

Comment: Filters (and segments) should work if you set the filter field to "request uri", condition to "contains" and enter your query parameters as value - if I understood correctly the query parameter is passed through to the iframe url, so it will show up in the request uri.